# When to use JAF activation

Tags: java

I wonder if I should use it, in this example. I'm reading files, and I need to store one parameter with that file.

According to this parameter I'm bundling files together and sending them over the wire.

I came accross jaf activation framework, and I'm not sure if it is appropriate to use it in such simple example.(store 'file' into DataHandler with this parameter or to make me simple holder). Of course I don't know if requirments can change in the future, and I will need more.

What do you think about it?

My impression is that it's too much, it's difficult to get proper sources. But on the other hand it has what I need.

The question could be more general as well, should I use framework which can do a lot more, if I need something really simple and I can code it quickly?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To answer your more general question, I would most often make use of frameworks wherever possible.

1. It's always possible that you're going to want more functionality in that area. If you're using the framework then great. Otherwise you have to back out and rewrite. Or maintain two different implementations.
2. Frameworks have been debugged/tested etc. and will handle the edge cases. Often what you think of as being trivial ends up more complicated than you first thought.

Don't forget that due to how class loading works, the JVM will only load the classes you require. Consequently you're only affecting the size of deployment of your application, not the runtime size (by referencing a sizable jar)